# Use of tee command promptly even for one command

Tags: linux, tee

I am new to using `tee` command.

I am trying to run one of my program which takes long time to finish but it prints out information as it progresses. I am using 'tee' to save the output to a file as well as to see the output in the shell (`bash`).

But the problem is `tee` doesn't forward the output to shell until the end of my command.
Is there any way to do that ?

I am using Debian and `bash`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This actually depends on the amount of output and the implementation of whatever command you are running. No program is obliged to print stuff straight to `stdout` or `stderr` and flush it all the time. So even though most C runtime implementation flush after a certain amount of data was written using one of the runtime routines, such as `printf`, this may not be true depending on the implementation.

It `tee` doesn't output it right away, it is likely only receiving the input at the very end of the run of your command. It *might* be helpful to mention which exact command it is.

Comment: You mentioned an excellent point! I forgot about the flushing. The command is one of my own C program. I added the fflush after my printf. Now it's working. Thank you very much for the prompt help.

Comment: @Rakib Hasan: glad it works for you now. It's an oft overlooked behavior, also in various scripting languages.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are experienced is most probably related to buffering.
You may have a look at stdbuf command, which does the following:

stdbuf - Run COMMAND, with modified buffering operations for its standard streams.

Answer (score 0):

If you were to post your usage I could give a better answer, but as it is

```
(for i in `seq 10`; do echo $i; sleep 1s; done) | tee ./tmp
```

Is proper usage of the tee command and seems to work. Replace the part before the pipe with your command and you should be good to go.